# Eclipse, unable to update or remove or add any new plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

Ever since a failed attempt at updating my plugins, I have been unable to update, remove, install or revert my plugins.

```
    The actions required to successfully install the requested software are incompatible with the software to install. 
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Mylyn Tasks Tests SDK 3.10.0.20131024-1218 (org.eclipse.mylyn.test_feature.feature.group 3.10.0.20131024-1218)
Missing requirement: Mylyn Task List 3.10.0.20131010-2023 (org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.10.0.20131010-2023) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui [3.10.0.20131009-1926]' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn Tasks SDK 3.10.0.20131024-1218 (org.eclipse.mylyn.sdk_feature.feature.group 3.10.0.20131024-1218)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group [3.10.0.20131010-2023]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn Tasks Tests SDK 3.10.0.20131024-1218 (org.eclipse.mylyn.test_feature.feature.group 3.10.0.20131024-1218)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn.sdk_feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

here is the list of plugins I have installed.

```
ADT Translation Manager plugin                             1.0.1.201309251931 
Android DDMS                                               22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 
Android Development Tools                              22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720
Android Hierarchy Viewer                               22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720
Android Native Development Tools                           22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 
Android Traceview                                      22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720
CollabNet Merge Client                                     3.0.13   
Command Line Interface for Java implementation of Git      3.3.0.201403021825-r
Command Line Interface for Java implementation of Git - Source Code    3.3.0.201403021825-r
Context and Dependency Injection Tools                 1.5.1.Final-v20131204-0116-B137  Eclipse Git Team Provider                          3.3.0.201403021825-r
Eclipse Git Team Provider - Source Code                3.3.0.201403021825-r
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers                 2.0.2.20140224-0000
Eclipse Quicksearch                                3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE   
Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.1                   1.9.1    
Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2                          3.5.1.v201312301719-rel-r42  
Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0                           2.6.0    
Gradle IDE                                         3.4.0.201310051517-RELEASE   
Grails (production release)                        2.2.4    
Grails IDE                                         3.4.0.201310051518-RELEASE
Groovy Compiler 1.8 Feature                      2.9.0.xx-20130828-1400-e43-RELEASE 
Groovy Compiler 2.0 Feature                      2.9.0.xx-20130828-1400-e43-RELEASE 
Groovy Compiler 2.1 Feature                      2.9.0.xx-20130828-1400-e43-RELEASE 
Groovy-Eclipse Feature                               2.9.0.xx-20130828-1400-e43-RELEASE 
Groovy-Eclipse M2E integration                       2.9.0.xx-20131205-1200-e43-RELEASE 
Hibernate Tools                                      3.7.1.Final-v20131205-0918-B107    
Java implementation of Git                       3.3.0.201403021825-r
Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient                                                   3.3.0.201403021825-r
Java implementation of Git - optional Java 7 libraries       3.3.0.201403021825-r   
Java implementation of Git - Source Code                 3.3.0.201403021825-r   
JBoss Archives Tools                                  3.4.101.Final-v20131206-1843-B159 
JBoss JAX-RS Tools                                1.5.1.Final-v20131206-1905-B127   
JBoss Maven CDI Configurator                          1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Maven Endorsed Libraries Configurator       1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator                1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Maven Integration                               1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Maven Project Examples                          1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Tools Apache Tomcat Integration                 1.0.1.Final-v20131206-1843-B159   
JBoss Tools Community Project Examples                1.5.3.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Tools Foundation                                1.0.1.Final-v20131204-1734-B141   
JBoss Tools Java Standard Tools                       3.5.1.Final-v20131203-2300-B112   
JBoss Tools Maven Packaging Configurator          1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Tools Maven Source Lookup                       1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126   
JBoss Tools Mobile Browser Simulator                  3.5.1.Final-v20131205-2101-B148   
JBoss WebServices Tools                               1.5.1.Final-v20131206-1905-B127   
JBossAS Tools                                        2.4.101.Final-v20131206-1843-B159  
JDT Core patch for Groovy-Eclipse plugin         2.9.0.xx-20130828-1400-e43-RELEASE 
JMX Console                                      1.4.1.Final-v20131206-1843-B159    
JNA Library                                      3.4.0.t20120117_1605
Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT                1.0.1.201209200721 
Maven Profiles Management                        1.5.4.Final-v20131204-2329-B126    
Maven SCM Handler for EGit                       0.14.0.201401060023    
Maven SCM handler for Subclipse                      0.13.0.201303011221    
Mylyn Builds                                         1.2.0.20131009-2205
Mylyn Builds Connector: Hudson/Jenkins               1.2.0.20131006-0226    
Mylyn Builds SDK                                 1.2.0.20131009-2205    
Mylyn Commons Compatibility                      3.10.0.20130621-1303   
Mylyn Commons Repositories HTTP Transport        1.2.0.20130704-2116    
Mylyn Commons SDK                                3.10.0.20131018-1210   
Mylyn Commons SOAP SDK                               3.10.0.20130704-2116   
Mylyn Context Connector: C/C++ Development       5.6.0.20131008-0520    
Mylyn Context Connector: Plug-in Development         3.10.0.20131008-0520   
Mylyn Context SDK                                3.10.0.20131008-2202   
Mylyn Docs EPUB SDK                              1.2.0.20131007-2055    
Mylyn Docs SDK                                       1.9.0.20131008-0518
Mylyn HtmlText                                       1.2.0.20130621-1305
Mylyn Reviews                                        2.1.0.20131025-2014
Mylyn Reviews Connector: Gerrit                      2.1.0.20131025-1517    
Mylyn Reviews SDK                                2.1.0.20131025-2014    
Mylyn Tasks Connector: Trac                      3.10.0.20130926-1945   
Mylyn Tasks SDK                                      3.10.0.20131024-1218
Mylyn Tasks Tests SDK                                3.10.0.20131024-1218   
Mylyn Versions                                       1.2.0.20130914-1512
Mylyn Versions Connector: CVS                        1.2.0.20130704-2112    
Mylyn Versions Connector: Git                        1.2.0.20130704-2112    
Mylyn Versions Connector: Subclipse              1.2.0.20130704-2112    
Mylyn Versions SDK                               1.2.0.20131003-0722    
Mylyn WikiText SDK                               1.9.0.20131008-0518    
Oracle WebLogic Server Tools                         6.4.0.201403011416
Oracle Project Examples                              1.5.3.Final-v20131204-2329-B126    
Spring Dashboard (optional)                      3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE
Spring IDE AJDT Developer Resources              3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE AJDT Integration (optional)               3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE AOP Developer Resources               3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE AOP Extension (optional)              3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Autowire Extension (optional)         3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Autowire Extension Developer Resource     3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Batch Developer Resources                 3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Batch Extension (optional)                3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Core (required)                       3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Core Developer Resources              3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Developer Resources  3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Extension (optional) 3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Maven Integration Developer Resources    3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE  Spring IDE Maven Support                            3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Mylyn Integration (optional)                 3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Mylyn Integration Sources                    3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE OSGi Extension (optional)                    3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE OSGi Extension Developer Resources           3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Roo Integration Developer Resources          3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Roo Support                                  3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Security Extension (optional)            3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Security Extension Developer Resources   3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE  Spring IDE Spring Data Integration Developer Resources  3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE  Spring IDE Spring Data Support                          3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Web Flow Extension (optional)            3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE
Spring IDE Web Flow Extension Developer Resources   3.4.0.201310051539-RELEASE  Spring Roo (production release)                         1.2.4.RELEASE
Spring UAA Integration (optional)                   3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE
Spring UAA Integration Developer Resources          3.4.0.201310051510-RELEASE
Subclipse (Required)                                    1.8.22
Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)          3.0.0
Subversion Client Adapter (Required)                    1.8.6
Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter            1.7.10
Subversion Revision Graph                           1.1.1
SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required)                    1.7.9.2
SVNKit Library                                          1.7.9.r9659_v20130411_2103
Task focused interface for Eclipse Git Team Provider    3.3.0.201403021825-r
Tracer for OpenGL ES                                    22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720
vFabric tc Server                                   2.9.4.RELEASE
VMware vFabric tc Server Integration for Eclipse    3.4.0.201310051547-RELEASE
VMware vFabric tc Server Spring Insight Integration for Eclipse 3.4.0.201310051547-RELEASE
```

I am looking for a solution that doesn't require deleting my plugins folder entirely.

Comment: wild guess: use the default release url, e.g. `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/` and untick "Contact all update sites on install" and then try to update/install

Comment: I see that from the official Mylyn repository, Mylyn version is 3.10. Instead, in Eclipse Kepler repository, Mylyn version is 3.9. Of course I can't downgrade because Mylyn is required by like a thousand of other plugins, so I guess the only option would be to reinstall Eclipse from scratch?
Android Developer tools was causing this issue (in my case). I uninstalled it and now I'm stuck with Eclipse without ADT. Misteries of Eclipse dependencies...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with "Missing requirement: Mylyn Task List 3.10.0.20131010-2023". I fixed it by closing the Task List panel in my workspace, uninstalling the 3.10 version (it did not completely uninstall as far as I can tell but it changed something), then checking for new software to find and install the 3.11 version.